# Python dataframe trimming: pd.concat() vs. df.drop() vs. df2 = df1[selectCols]

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, concatenation

Dataframe `df1` contains columns `Week`, `Mon`:`Sun`, `Total`.

Here are 3 ways to create a new dataframe 'df2' from columns in df1:

```
df2 = pd.concat(
    [df1.Sun,df1.Mon, 
    df1.Tues, df1.Weds,
    df1.Thurs, df1.Fri,
    df1.Sat], axis=1)

df2 = df1.drop(['Week', 'Total'], axis=1)

df2 = df1[['Sun','Mon','Tues','Weds','Thurs','Fri','Sat']]
```

How are these different?  In what situation is each advantageous?

Comment: Is this R or Python?

Comment: If you attach some example or part of dataframe it would be easier to test these methods

Comment: Definitely not the first one; it's long, ugly and inefficient. The other two would depend on the situation, e.g. you might be selecting relatively few columns or dropping relatively few, as in the example above. You might also want to be explicit to a reader of the code which columns are being selected (or dropped). I doubts there's anything between them in term of memory usage

Comment: Also, `drop` can be configured to drop columns which may or may not be there by passing `errors='ignore'`

Comment: what exactly is df2 - has it been initialized prior to this step?

Answer (score 0):

I figure the main advantage would be processing time. I took your examples, made some sample data, and compared them using the [timeit](https://docs.python.org/2/library/timeit.html) library. It looks like options 2 and 3 are a lot faster. I would use option 2 if there are a lot of columns and it's inconvenient to write them all out, and vice-versa for option 3. Hope this helps.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
daysOfWeek = ['Sun','Mon','Tues','Weds','Thurs','Fri','Sat', 'Week', 'Total']

df1 = pd.DataFrame()

for i in range(0, len(daysOfWeek)):
    #create array with random numbers
    df1[daysOfWeek[i]] = np.random.randint(0,10,500)
print(df1.head())
```

First option: 100 loops, best of 3: 1.01 ms per loop

```
%%timeit -n 100
df2 = pd.concat(
    [df1.Sun,df1.Mon, 
    df1.Tues, df1.Weds,
    df1.Thurs, df1.Fri,
    df1.Sat], axis=1)
```

Second option: 100 loops, best of 3: 743 µs per loop

```
df2 = df1.drop(['Week', 'Total'], axis=1)
```

Third option: 100 loops, best of 3: 838 µs per loop

```
df2 = df1[['Sun','Mon','Tues','Weds','Thurs','Fri','Sat']]
```